# How do I get the real position of a FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, position, frameworkelement

I am doing `rotationTransform` and `scaleTransform` in a ellipse which is inside a usercontrol.
I already tried this, but didn't work.

```
Point myUiElementPosition = 
   ellipse.TransformToAncestor(this.Parent as Panel).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

I'm using the mouse to rotate the object, but the code above always return the same value!

What am I doing wrong? I already tried to put `App.Current.MainWindow` instead of `this.Parent as Panel`.

I also tried using `this` instead of `ellipse`.

Help!

Comment: Do you use RenderTransform or LayoutTransform?

Comment: I use renderTransform. I guess it does makes difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ellipse.Parent` instead of `this.Parent`. I hope this will help.

Comment: I am not sure how this worked. But the transforms were inside the ellipse. Now I putted inside the main panel, and the old code to get the position worked. =o